# How to make sure JWT token was generated in specific application?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, jwt

I have an API that's publicly available that requires a JWT token. I only want to accept tokens coming from a specific application. This application uses oauth 2.0 and receives the JWT from AAD which is then sent over to my API. I'd like to make sure the ONLY THIS APPLICATION is allowed to use my API.

Currently I'm using the `TokenValidationParameters` class in `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` to validate tokens, which field should I use to validate the caller of my API? Note that only one other application should ever be able to call my API. Should I use one or multiple of the following?

- audience
- issuer
- signature key

Or should I create some custom authorization instead?

Comment: want you'll probably want is to establish trust with that other application. so it would be required that the other application mentions you among the audience(s) of its access token, and you check for the presence of that audience in your validation. another idea would be to regard that other application as one (the only) possible client(s) of your API, and require a certain client claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a combination of `audience` (make sure that the JWT token is intended for the app in question), `issuer` (make sure that the JWT token is being issued by the backend in question) and `signature` to make sure that the token hasn't been tampered with.

There is an excellent write-up on JWT token best practices [here.](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/)